# Convert php Herirachical array to view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, treeview

I have a `heirachical` DB structure. Using `Recurisive` function i have  stored the `db` values in heirarchical structure array. So now i want display the array in well format in `view` .(like a `tree`). Is there any `library` in codeigniter supporting that. ?

DB

```
 PK  parent  name
    -------------------------
    1   0       Animals
    2   1       Cat
```

My array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
         [PK] => 1
         [parent] => 0
         [name] => Animals
         [childs] => Array
                        (
                        [0] => Array 
                            (
                             [PK] => 2
                             [parent] => 1
                             [name] => Cat
                        )
        )
)
```

Comment: Do you like to know if it possible in java, php or javascript? Delete tags not relative to your question please

Comment: there is no tree library in codeigniter from the box